# how to hit the service url everyday 7 am using NStimer in IOS?

Tags: ios

```
- (NSTimer *) timer 
{
     (!_timer)
     {
        _timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:86400 target:self selector:@selector(timeset:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
     }
     return _timer;
}
```

Comment: you can use local notification for this

Answer (score 0):

You can't schedule execution for a specific time in the background on iOS.  You can schedule a `UILocalNotification` - but your app will only be launched if the user taps on the notification.

Your best bet is to use background fetch mode.  You app will be woken at intervals and given an opportunity to fetch new data.  You can check to see if the time is at or after 7 and decide whether to refresh the data.